# Evaluating definite integral with functions as limits

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, substitution

This was a physics example regarding electric field, but I need some help in the **calculation part**.

Positive charge $Q$ is uniformly distributed along the $y-axis$ between $y=-a$ and $y=+a$. Find the electric field $P$ on the $x-axis$ at a distance $x$ from the origin

So the electric field is generated by a rod, which is broke into infinitesimal segments.

**Rod below**

| <== $dy$

|

| -------------$x$------------ $P$

|

|

Each segment is called $dy$

$x$ is the distance from $P$ to the rod

$2a$ is the length of rod

$Q$ is total charge, $Q/2a$ is the linear charge density

After a series of steps, the textbook reached the following step, for the $x$ component of the electric field:
$$ E_{x} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x{\,}dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} $$

the detail of evaluation was omitted in the textbook, but it's evaluated to  $$ E_{x} = \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt {x^2+a^2}} $$

I spent a good deal of time trying to evaluate this integral myself using substitution but all met dead ends. I need some guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is essentially the followig indefinite integral:
\begin{align}
\int \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\,dy
&=\int \frac{\cos u}{x^2}du& (y=x\tan(u),\ dy=x\sec^2(u)du)\\
&=\frac{\sin(u)}{x^2}+C\\
&=\frac{\sin(\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x})}{x^2}+C\\
&=\frac{y}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}+C
\end{align}

It follows that
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^a\frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}dy
&=2x\int_{0}^a\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}dy\\
&=2x\cdot \frac{y}{x^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\big|_{y=0}^{y=a}\\
&=\frac{2a}{x\sqrt{x^2+a^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: How did you find the correct substitution?

Comment: @SirouEwei: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution In particular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution#Case_II:_Integrands_containing_%7F'%22%60UNIQ--postMath-0000002F-QINU%60%22'%7F

Comment: Thank you, looks like the text went a bit beyond the scope.

Comment: @SirouEwei: if you have a calculus textbook, look for the section "trigonometric substitutions" or something like that. That is a standard calculus 101 topic.

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that $x$ is a constant with respect to the variable of integration, and so

\begin{align}
E_{x} &= \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{x{\,}dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\\
& = \frac{x}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}.
\end{align}

Now, let
\begin{align}
y &= x\tan(u)\\
dy &= x\sec^{2}(u)\,du.
\end{align}

Then, using the identity $\tan^2(u) + 1 = \sec^2(u)$, we obtain
\begin{align}
\int \frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} &=\int\frac{x\sec^{2}(u)\,du}{(x^{2} + x^{2}\tan^{2}(u))^{3/2}}\\
&=\int\frac{x\sec^{2}(u)\,du}{(x^{2}\sec^2(u))^{3/2}}\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{2}}\int \cos(u)\,du\\
&=\frac{1}{x^{2}}\sin(u) + C.
\end{align}

Now, $$\tan(u) = \frac{y}{x} \implies \sin(u) = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},$$ and so we have $$\int \frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{y}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}} + C.$$  Using this to evaluate the definite integral:
$$\int_{-a}^{a} \frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{y}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}\Bigg|_{-a}^{a} = \frac{2a}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}.$$  Putting everything back together, then, we obtain
$$E_{x} = \frac{x}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{2a} \int_{-a}^{a} \frac{dy}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{x}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{Q}{2a}\frac{2a}{x^{2}\sqrt{x^2 + a^2}}=\frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}} \frac{1}{x \sqrt {x^2+a^2}}.$$